# select distinct list of ids from table with earliest value in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table,

```
 SDate         Id       Balance
 2016-01-01    ABC      3
 2016-01-01    DEF      7
 2016-01-01    GHI      2

 2016-02-01    ABC      6
 2016-02-01    DEF      4
 2016-02-01    GHI      8
 2016-02-01    XYZ      12
```

I need to write a query that gives me a distinct list of Id's over a date range (so in this example `SDate >= '2016-01-01'` and `SDate <= '2016-02-01'`) but also give me the earliest balance so the result from the table above I would like to see is,

```
 Id       Balance
 ABC      3
 DEF      7
 GHI      2
 XYZ      12
```

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Sorry I should have specified that for each date the Id is unique.

Comment: I assume that Id + SDate is unique, else you could have more then 1 Balance

Comment: sorry good point let me update my question quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with a window function - all you have to do is

- partition by id
- assign a row number, and
- select the top row for each id

Example:

```
select  id,
        balance
from    (
            select  id,
                    balance,
                    row_number() over( partition by id order by SDate ) as row_num
            from    table1
            where   SDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-02-01'
        ) as a
where   row_num = 1
```

Note: the advantage of this method is it is a lot more flexible.  Say you wanted the 2 oldest records, you could just change to `where row_num <= 2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a derived table that first works out the minimum `SDate` value for each `Id` value.  Using this you then `join` back to your original table to find the `Balance` for the row that matches those values:

```
declare @t table(SDate date,Id nvarchar(3),Balance int);
insert into @t values ('2016-01-01','ABC',3),('2016-01-01','DEF',7),('2016-01-01','GHI',2),('2016-02-01','ABC',6),('2016-02-01','DEF',4),('2016-02-01','GHI',8),('2016-02-01','XYZ',12);

declare @StartDate date = '20160101';
declare @EndDate date = '20160201';

with d as
(
    select Id
          ,min(SDate) as MinSDate
    from @t
    where SDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
    group by id
)
select d.Id
      ,t.Balance
from d
    inner join @t t
        on(d.Id = t.Id
           and d.MinSDate = t.SDate
          );
```

Output:

```
Id  | Balance
----+--------
ABC | 3
DEF | 7
GHI | 2
XYZ | 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a self join, which may not be the fastest or most elegant solution:

```
 CREATE TABLE #SOPostSample
    (
      SDate DATE ,
      Id NVARCHAR(5) ,
      Balance INT
    );

 INSERT INTO #SOPostSample
        ( SDate, Id, Balance )
 VALUES ( '2016-01-01', 'ABC', 3 ),
        ( '2016-01-01', 'DEF', 7 ),
        ( '2016-01-01', 'GHI', 2 ),
        ( '2016-02-01', 'ABC', 6 ),
        ( '2016-02-01', 'DEF', 4 ),
        ( '2016-02-01', 'GHI', 8 ),
        ( '2016-02-01', 'XYZ', 12 );

 SELECT t1.Id ,
        MIN(t2.Balance) Balance
 FROM   #SOPostSample t1
        INNER JOIN #SOPostSample t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
 GROUP BY t1.Id ,
        t2.SDate
 HAVING t2.SDate = MIN(t1.SDate);

 DROP TABLE #SOPostSample;
```

Produces:

```
id   Balance
============
ABC  3
DEF  7
GHI  2
XYZ  12
```

This works for the sample data, but please test with more data as I just wrote it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Analytic `row_number()` should be the fastest

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by Id order by SDate) rn
    from your_table t
) t where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query

```
SELECT  Id ,
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                    Balance
          FROM      [TableName] AS T1
          WHERE     T1.Id = [TableName].Id
          ORDER BY  SDate
        ) AS Balance
FROM    [TableName]
GROUP BY Id;
```

Comment: Sub selects within your `select` statement are a big performance killer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, Top 1 just inserted for safety, should not be needed if SDate and Id are unique in combination

```
SELECT  o.Id ,
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                    Balance
          FROM      tbl
          WHERE     Id = o.Id
                    AND SDate = MIN(o.SDate)
        ) Balance
FROM    tbl o
GROUP BY Id
HAVING  sDate BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160201';
```

Comment: Sub selects within your `select` statement are a big performance killer.